# AlertDialog or Toast while updating database android

Tags: android, database, updating

I have an app with a database. While the data are updating, I'd like to show an `AlertDialog` or a `Toast` with a turning circle.

Comment: Are you using a task/ asynctask to do this? and what version of android would this before?

Comment: database from where? this may be a database that is on the device itself or hosted somewhere. In case it is hosted, you can make use of AsyncTask for this. Show dialog on dall for the service then onPostExecute close that dialog or show a toast message. Moreover, toast can't have that turning circle. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you would have to do all the transactions in `Background Thread` using AsyncTask.
You can then simply display a `ProgressDialog` on the `UI Thread` while the transaction processes in the Background Thread.

Here is a simple Template of `AsyncTask` that includes a turning circle a.k.a `ProgressBar` within the `ProgressDialog`

```
private class UpdateDataBaseAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> 
{

ProgressDialog pd;  

public UpdateDataBaseAsyncTask (..Your set of Variables for updating database..)
{
    pd = new ProgressDialog(cntx);
    pd.setTitle("Updating ...");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    //Initialization of your Database Handler, and other Database Transaction related objects.

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        //Start Database Tranaction Here !
        //If the Transaction is successful, pass the boolean as true *result = true;*
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("YOUR TAG", "Error occured while updating Database !, Error = "+e.toStirng());
        //e.printStackTrace(); optional
        result = false;
    }

return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    pd.dismiss();

    if(result)
    {
        //tasks you want to perform when the database is successfully updated
    }
    else
    {
        //Show a failure Dialog here may be.
    }

}
}
```

**Edit:**
`Executing the AsyncTask`

This is how you can execute it:

```
YourActivity extends Activity
{
...
...
...
onCreate(...)
{
 //Your Implementation
 ...
 ...
 ...

 //Calling the AsyncTask
 new UpdateDataBaseAsyncTask(...).execute();
}
...
...
...
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It works fine but when finish...
 
    01-22 18:55:17.602: W/dalvikvm(1038): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-22 18:55:17.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Please share the code of your Async Class.

Answer (score 0):

I've solucionated the problem with Looper Prepare()